# Are Riemann integrable functions the pointwise limit of continuous functions?

Tags: continuity, riemann-integration, pointwise-convergence

> Given a function $f$ that is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, does there exist a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ that converges to $f$ pointwise everywhere on $[a,b]$?

If I just require pointwise almost everywhere, this follows from the fact that continuous functions are dense in $L^1[a,b]$ and norm convergence yields a subsequence that converges a.e. This is an exercise in Krantz, Real Analysis and Foundations (4th ed., p. 153); I have not been able to prove it, and when I queried the author he could not provide a proof either. However, I cannot find a counter-example, either.

Answer (score 2):

Everywhere? no.  Almost everywhere, yes.

A pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous functions is said to be a function of [Baire class $1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_function#Baire_class_1).  Baire proved many properties of such functions.  In particular, if $E$ is a nonempty perfect set, then the restriction of $f$ to $E$ has a point of continuity.

Consider the following function $f$.  Let $[a,b] = [0,1]$.  Let $C$ be the middle-thirds Cantor set.  So $C$ is a closed set of measure zero.  Define $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ as follows.
$\bullet \;f(x) = 0$ on $[0,1]\setminus C$.
$\bullet\;f(x) = 0$ on the endpoints
of the open intervals in $[0,1]\setminus C$.
$\bullet\;f(x) = 1$ elsewhere, uncountably many remaining points of $C$.

First note that $f$ is continuous at every point of $[0,1]\setminus C$,
a set of measure $1$, so $f$ is Riemann integrable.

But also note that the restriction of $f$ to the nonempty perfect set $C$ has no point of continuity: both $\{x \in C : f(x) = 0\}$ and $\{x \in C : f(x) = 1\}$ are dense in $C$.  So $f$ is not of Baire class $1$.